# Webservice - How to implement an anti phishing key in a service that accept a callback

Tags: python, django, web-services, security, phishing

I need to implement a web service that will receive a callback.

In my web application I will need to implement something like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/callback?key=[an_anti_phishing_key]&otherparam1=[something1]&otherparam2=[something2]
```

A detailed explanation. There will be a 3rd party service that will request this URL with this parameters. And this service need that I implement an "anti phishing key" so that they can communicate securely with mywebsite.com

My doubt here is how to implement this anti phishing key in a secure manner.

Any ideas of possible implementations?

Comment: What platform are you using? j2ee?

Comment: Hi John Saunders, I'm using Python/Django

Comment: What exactly does this "anti_phishing_key"? Is it a one time usage? Please provide more details if it's possible.

Comment: Hi Igarr. The "anti_phishing_key" is a key that I will send to a 3rd party service so that they can make requests to my callback. The key will be always the same.

Comment: @André: it's good to give platform information in the tags

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `GET` request as a client to the server over `HTTP`, it is susceptible to a Man-in-the-middle attack. What you can do is to allow only `POST` requests over `HTTPS`. That would be more secure than the former.